# Java blocking arara

Tags: texshop, arara, java

Experiencing what appears to be java blocking arara when typesetting using TeXShop on the following code when run on an M2 Mac with Ventura OS:

```
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeglossaries if missing('gls') || changed('glo')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v30a9.ist }
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v30a9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
% arara: nomencl 
% arara: makeglossaries if found('aux', '@istfilename')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: makeindex: { style: Differ2Latex-v30a9.ist } if changed ('idx') || missing ('ind')
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: authorindex
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: on }
```

The errors are as follows:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing "Differ2Latex-v30a9.tex" (size: 3.0 MB, last modified:
2023-09-29 08:23:14), please wait.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Compiler
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.setupParser(AbstractParser.java:215)
    at org.mvel2.compiler.AbstractParser.<clinit>(AbstractParser.java:153)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.compileExpression(MVEL.java:831)
    at org.mvel2.templates.res.CompiledExpressionNode.<init>(CompiledExpressionNode.java:41)
    at org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compileFrom(TemplateCompiler.java:211)
    at org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:82)
    at org.mvel2.templates.TemplateCompiler.compileTemplate(TemplateCompiler.java:348)
    at org.mvel2.templates.TemplateRuntime.eval(TemplateRuntime.java:91)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.mvel.rules.RuleArgument$1.invoke(RuleArgument.kt:51)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.mvel.rules.RuleArgument$1.invoke(RuleArgument.kt:41)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.interpreter.Interpreter.processArgument(Interpreter.kt:425)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.interpreter.Interpreter.parseArguments(Interpreter.kt:386)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.interpreter.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.kt:282)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.ruleset.DirectiveImpl.execute(DirectiveImpl.kt:25)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.core.session.LinearExecutor.execute(LinearExecutor.kt:114)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.core.session.LinearExecutor.executeProject$core(LinearExecutor.kt:89)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.core.session.LinearExecutor.execute(LinearExecutor.kt:73)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLI.run(CLI.kt:318)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:198)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.parsers.Parser.parse(Parser.kt:18)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse(CliktCommand.kt:393)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse$default(CliktCommand.kt:390)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:408)
    at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:433)
    at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLIKt.main(CLI.kt:366)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.Compiler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 25 more
```

I've tried reinstalling java, and "java -version" in Terminal reveals:

```
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Checked java security panel, but nothing leaps out as to what is causing the block.

Any thoughts as to what to check next wold be appreciated.

Comment: Recently on `arara`'s Matrix discussion group, something like this appeared. They had suggested downgrading JVM to 17 which was the last LTS before 21.

Comment: https://matrix.to/#/!HfEWIEvFtDplCLSQvz:matrix.org/$ylCOgZ5P5rbhbrDZWtSOtqDq6RUMI9_WuJwNdmzgmuc?via=matrix.org&via=gitter.im&via=t2bot.io

Comment: @MS-SPO the question looks well-formed. They have given proper context with the log.

Comment: @MS-SPO arara is a TeX build tool, it's absolutely on topic here (TeX tooling usually is) and its main developers respond here quite often. And the question is indeed quite well-formed with Niranjan having spotted the issue (JVM 21 with which arara currently is incompatible) immediately.

Comment: We have published arara version 7.1.1 today which fixes this issue. It should hit your TeX distribution in the next few days.

Comment: @TeXnician I'm still running into this issue today with version 7.1.2 on MikTeX (MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.16 (MiKTeX 23.10.12)), java (openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-29)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-29, mixed mode, sharing)). Do you want me to open another question ?

Comment: @BambOo No, this site is not an issue tracker. If the bug persists, please open an issue in the arara repository with some more details so that we can involve our Windows testers. The solution to the bug will be hit and miss as long as we don't have Windows users as contributors to arara, so let's see how many iterations we will need.

Comment: @TeXnician, I did not mean to post the issues here of course ^^. I was just wondering if this was just me missing some appropriate version of the package. I'll open an issue right now