# Arara doesn't work anymore after package update to v 7.1.1

Tags: texlive, arara, java, latex-workshop

**I am writing Latex code in VSCode with TexLive installed on Windows 10** and I am using Arara.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
%! arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
%! arara: pdflatex
```

**Everything worked perfectly till yesterday when, after reading this question [Java blocking arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697218/java-blocking-arara), I've updated Arara to the newest version 7.1.1**.

**Previously, before updating Arara to v7.1.1, I had *Java RE* installed and Arara worked fine** and running `java -version` in Terminal resulted in:

```
java version "1.8.0_381"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.381-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

For other purposes I had to install *open jdk 21* and running `java -version` in Terminal results **now** in:

```
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21+35-2513)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-2513, mixed mode, sharing)
```

From one comment below that question I've read that the incompatibility of Arara with Java 21 would have been fixed with Arara 7.1.1 version.

Now I've updated Arara package via *tlmgr* to version 7.1.1 but when I build my Latex project I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain class com.sun.jna.CallbackReference
at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:248)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.internal.Win32MppImpls.<init>(JnaMppImplsWin32.kt:73)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.internal.MppImplKt.<clinit>(MppImpl.kt:96)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.TerminalDetection.isJediTerm(TerminalDetection.kt:143)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.TerminalDetection.isIntellijRunActionConsole(TerminalDetection.kt:169)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.TerminalDetection.detectTerminal(TerminalDetection.kt:16)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.StdoutTerminalInterface.<init>(StdoutTerminalInterface.kt:17)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.Terminal.<init>(Terminal.kt:56)
at com.github.ajalt.mordant.terminal.Terminal.<init>(Terminal.kt:45)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.Context$Builder.<init>(Context.kt:227)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.Context$Companion.build$clikt(Context.kt:312)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.createContext(CliktCommand.kt:141)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse(CliktCommand.kt:456)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.parse$default(CliktCommand.kt:455)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:475)
at com.github.ajalt.clikt.core.CliktCommand.main(CliktCommand.kt:482)
at org.islandoftex.arara.cli.CLIKt.main(CLI.kt:382)
```

I've tried to delete *Open JdK 21* from my PC and reinstall *Java R*e but *Arara v 7.1.1* still does not work.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697218/java-blocking-arara#comment1731874_697218

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz In my question I mentioned that I updated arara package _after_ I've read the question in your link. In the comments below that question they say that with this new arara version (7.1.1) the compatiblity with java 21 would have beeen fixed. Unfortunately it doesn't seems the case.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I missed this part!

Comment: If you have a matrix account, you can directly talk to the arara maintainers there (see the link below the other question) You could also try https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends If I remember correctly, chat has a lower rep requirement and both @ TeXnician as well as @ PauloCereda are there regularly.

Comment: Summary from TeX.SX chat: [This is a known issue](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/119) and Windows users are advised to stay at version 7.1.0 (or alternatively help debug/resolve the issue upstream). 7.1.1 is a bugfix release for JDK 21 and woks on unixoid platforms so do not update if you don't need that bugfix (there are no new features in that release).

Comment: Hi there! We've sent version 7.1.2 to CTAN. Hopefully, it will hit mirrors soon and this issue with Windows will be fixed. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in downgrading to 7.1.0 version for TeXlive

If running `tlmgr option autobackup` returns a positive number, like

```
tlmgr option autobackup
Number of backups to keep (autobackup): 1
```

then you can run `tlmgr restore arara 67201` to restore arara v7.1.0.

Solution taken from [here](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/issues/119)

Edit1:  Of course you **must not run JVM 21 if you downgrade to 7.1.0** otherwise it will continue to not work.

Edit2: See the above comment of @TeXnician